# Two forms submitting at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I'm creating a landing page and I have two separate forms to submit email addresses and I'm using Parse to store them.

The problem I submit an email address on the first form, it creates two objects - one with the email address in the form and the second is blank. When I submit an email address in the second form, it submits as expected one object, one email address.

From this, I can only conclude that the second form is being submitted concurrently when I submit the first form.

Here's what I get in the console:

```
 Subscribe                                           Parse.js:39

                                                     Parse.js:48

 Notify Me                                           Parse.js:7

 test@test.com                                       Parse.js:16

 New object created with objectId: FodANtALX8        Parse.js:21

 New object created with objectId: hLYyCNVSaW        Parse.js:53
```

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".input-group-btn").click(function() {
    console.log("Notify Me");

    var Address = $(".form-control").val();

    var Email = Parse.Object.extend("Email");
    var email = new Email();

    email.set("Address", Address);

    console.log(Address);

    email.save(null, {
        success: function(email) {
            // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
            console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + email.id);

        },
        error: function(email, error) {
            // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
            alert('Could not accept email address: ' + error.message);
        }
    });

});


$(".btn-wide").click(function() {
    console.log("Buy");
});

$(".btn-primary").click(function() {
    console.log("Subscribe");

    var Address = $(".subinput").val();

    var Email = Parse.Object.extend("Email");
    var email = new Email();

    email.set("Address", Address);

    console.log(Address);

    email.save(null, {
        success: function(email) {
            // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
            console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + email.id);
            $('.subinput').val("");
        },
        error: function(email, error) {
            // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
            alert('Could not accept email address: ' + error.message);
        }
    });

});

});
```

And are the corresponding sections of the HTML:

```
<form>
      <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="person@gmail.com">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Notify Me</button>
           </span>
      </div>
</form>


<form>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
         <input type="text" class="subinput" placeholder="Enter your email for updates" spellcheck="false">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">
              Subscribe now
           </button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML, it's possible that your two form elements share a class, and your eventhandler finds two forms when one button is clicked. A good way to fix this is associate unique ID's to your events rather than classes.

Comment: @bencripps HTML added.

Comment: Both of your `click` handlers are firing due to the classes you are using for the binding. `ID` your buttons instead. Or better yet, track the `submit` event on each `form` instead of the `click` event on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Subscribe` function you are asking jquery to look for `btn-primary` which is a css class shared by both of your buttons. Add a unique id to your buttons and have jquery look for this to avoid a recurrence of this issue.